# Global install of a program built in sandbox

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I'm using sandboxes all the time when building Haskell programs and libraries. But occasionally, I build a program that I would like to install system wide. There doesn't seem to be an easy way of taking a program which is built in a sandbox and installing it outside of the sandbox.

Answer (score 3):

### Linking **Idris** to a PATH-folder

If you are on linux it's as simple as putting a symbolic link somewhere into your path - I have a `~/bin` for that. So it's the same as bheklilr mentioned only that I usually get the dev-version from github:

```
git clone git://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev idris
cd idris
cabal sandbox init
cabal update
cabal install --dependencies only
make
```

after this I go to `~/bin` and use `ln -s [path to idris]/.cabal-sandbox/bin/idris` - you can link the other executables too if you like but this one will should be enough to play with *idris*

Comment: Thanks. That's a very simple and pragmatic solution. Though I still wish cabal provided a means to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the binary is statically linked (which is true in most cases) then you can do the following

```
> mkdir tools
> cd tools
> cabal sandbox init
> cabal install tool1 tool2
# Wait a long time
> cp .cabal-sandbox/bin/tool1 ~/.cabal/bin
> cp .cabal-sandbox/bin/tool2 ~/.cabal/bin
```

On windows you'll have to do

```
> cp .cabal-sandbox\bin\tool1.exe %APPDATA%\Roaming\cabal\bin
> cp .cabal-sandbox\bin\tool2.exe %APPDATA%\Roaming\cabal\bin
```

Obviously you should have your user cabal directory on your path.

Your mileage may vary, it's dependent on the executable being built, so for some it might be more difficult to do this sort of thing.  In my experience this works pretty well, though.  I use it for ghc-mod, hlint, pointfree, and others.

Comment: The program I currently want to install is idris which comes with a ton of extra stuff like libraries. I'd like to avoid having to figure out how to copy all that data by hand.